# How can I create a gravitational attraction between objects with cannon.js and three.js?

Tags: three.js, physics, cannon.js

I can create gravity in the whole world but I want to create a gravitational attraction between objects so I can simulate planets and stuff.

I tried making a function for Newton's law of universal gravitation but I don't know where to start at all. It might work but I thought it might be annoying because I'd have to add every object I make. Sorry if this is a bad post.